# Styling HTML5 Audio Player

Tags: javascript, html, css

From HTML5 audio player I create a stylish audio player, the whole design and functions works perfectly but I struck in one problem.

I change the volume position from vertical to horizontal, means `.pageY` to `.pageX`.

Now the problem is when I drag the volume from left to right it decrease the volume and when drag the volume from right to left it increase the volume.

I change the following code:

```
adjustVolume = function( e )
{
    theRealEvent    = isTouch ? e.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] : e;
    theAudio.volume = Math.abs( ( theRealEvent.pageY - ( volumeAdjuster.offset().top + volumeAdjuster.height() ) ) / volumeAdjuster.height() );
},
```

To this:

```
adjustVolume = function( e )
{
    theRealEvent    = isTouch ? e.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] : e;
    theAudio.volume = Math.abs( ( theRealEvent.pageX - ( volumeAdjuster.offset().left + volumeAdjuster.width() ) ) / volumeAdjuster.width() );
},
```

what I want is to just correct them, like they work in other website (youtube etc)

## Here's the [jsFeedle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvFAm/)

Thanks! in advance.

---

**Edit:** From the play which is taught to make in [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/04/responsive-touch-friendly-audio-player/), I make my player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest fix, without diving deeper into the mathematics of it: Set the value to 1 minus the value you have calculated now,

```
theAudio.volume = 1 - Math.abs(…)
```

Comment: Thanks! It was simple but I'm new in JS, Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, I did not dive deeper into the mathematics of your actual volume calculation, with the event position, offset and width … but if you have a value that is _supposed_ to go from 0 to 1, and it goes from 1 to 0 instead … well then using `1 - (value)` as the actual value naturally corrects that, that is just basic simple math :-)